# Podspec s.vendored_frameworks not working

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

Maybe I misunderstood the way of `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` work but I'm trying to use/integrate the [Sinch.framework](https://www.sinch.com/ios-sdk) in my own SDK (for the voip part) but in my ReplaceMe.swift I'm not able to import or use any stuff from it

My hierarchy after I used `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` is the following
[image: My hierarchy]

My podspec (last version of cocoapods is used)

```
  s.ios.source_files = 'PoCSDK/Classes/**/*','PoCSDK/Frameworks/Sinch.frameworks/Headers/*'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'PoCSDK/Sinch.framework'
  s.ios.public_header_files = 'PoCSDK/Frameworks/Sinch.frameworks/Headers/*'

  s.resource_bundles = {
     'NoddsSDK' => ['PoCSDK/Assets/*']
  }

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit', 'AudioToolbox', 'AVFoundation'
  s.ios.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
  s.ios.dependency 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
  s.ios.dependency 'ReachabilitySwift'
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 15):

What I did to add Fabric and Crashlytics to my development pod:

1. Create Frameworks folder in your Development pod folder
2. Copy your frameworks to the folder
3. Update your pod spec

   ```
   s.vendored_frameworks = 'podname/Frameworks/Fabric.framework', 'podname/Frameworks/Crashlytics.framework'

   s.preserve_path = 'podname/Frameworks/*'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the real project structure in finder rather than those in Xcode? 
Because I put my "Finder" path in `vendored_frameworks` and all worked for me.

Comment: Hi @Mattia, how did you find `vendored_frameworks` in Finder?